# Resolving Symbolic Links While Avoiding Timeout

Tags: c, posix, symlink, nfs

I am currently resolving a list of symbolic links in C (POSIX environment). Some of which point to an NFS. Some of the NFS have been taken offline temporarily. Is there a way to avoid or minimize timeouts when resolving an offline NFS?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to avoid those waits would be to test in advance whether that NFS directory is available, and if not to unmount it so it appears as a local empty directory (which would fail quickly).

Or you could use a protocol other than NFS, which would let you set timeouts more explicitly.

Comment: What does the National Science Foundation have to do with the Networked File System?

Comment: "Dyslexics of the world, UNTIE!" ... fixed.